# Text in ToolBarItem won't update @AppStorage value until I click outside of the ToolBar

Tags: swiftui-toolbar

So I'm working on a little project that has a ToolBar with 4 ToolBarItems on it.
Buton...Text...Text...Button

The 2nd text item displays a database version number that is extracted from a downloaded file and added to @AppStorage and that function to get the data is called from the last button.

I put code into the function to print the outputs and it shows the correct data and updates the @AppStorage variable, but the text field doesn't update until I click outside of the ToolBar, then the text field will update.  I was under the impression that updating an @AppStorage variable will update the view but I think I'm missing something.

I'm fairly new to Swiftui so be gentle!

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.topBarTrailing) {
    Text(verbatim: "Ver. \(fileDatabase)")
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .font(.title2)
         .foregroundColor(databaseVersionColor)
                        
     Button("", systemImage: "square.stack.3d.up.fill") {
         getData()
     }.buttonStyle(GrowingButton())
}
```

The (fileDatabase) field is what gets updated in @AppStorage